# How do you schedule tasks with bamboo like Jenkins or cron

Tags: bamboo

I am a new user with bamboo. As I know, Jenkins can do scheduled tasks by setting a value like cron `:* * 5 5 5`, but I don't how I can achieve this with bamboo.

For example, I want a task to be run at 10:00pm every day.

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, yes, scheduled tasks are possible:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/cron-based-scheduling-289276907.html

> Using a cron-based schedule to trigger the build of a plan is one of
>   the available methods for triggering builds in Bamboo. This schedule
>   is configured using the Schedule Editor. The schedule can be daily
>   (times per day), weekly (days per week), monthly (days per month) or
>   based on a cron expression.
>
> To schedule a plan build using a cron expression:
>
> 1. Click Dashboard and then the All Plans tab.
> 2. Locate the plan in the list and click the edit icon ([image]) to display the plan's configuration pages.
> 3. Click the Triggers tab, then click either an existing trigger
>      or Add Trigger.
> 4. Optionally, enter a trigger description.
> 5. Choose Trigger type > Cron Based Scheduling.
> 6. Click the edit icon ([image]) next to the current schedule to display the Schedule Editor.
> 7. Use the Schedule Editor (see screenshots below), to specify the build schedule for your plan. For information about cron expressions, see this FAQ: 
>      [Constructing a cron expression in Bamboo.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/constructing-a-cron-expression-in-bamboo-289277372.html)
> 8. Click Save Trigger.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]